# Generic type specified by inherits

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I do not think what I want is possible, but I hope someone can verify this and maybe explain why it is impossible.

We have an inheritance of `Bar<T>`, for which we cannot touch the source code of `Bar<T>`

```
abstract class Foo<T> : Bar<T>
```

We offer `Foo<T>` to be implemented by a third party, and we also want to dictate that whatever class inherits from `Foo<T>` is the specified type for `T`.
This can of course be done manually by the third party, for instance

```
class Fizz : Foo<Fizz>
```

However, I find the repetition of `Fizz` cumbersome and ugly.
Is it possible to have `Foo<T>` automatically use `Fizz` as the specified type for `T`?
In other words, is it possible to let `Foo<T>` be implemented something along these lines

```
abstract class Foo : Bar<T>
    where T : "Whatever class inherits from Foo"
```

... which I do not believe is possible because I cannot find a fitting generic type constraint.
Is it possible to do something like this instead

```
[SomeBlackMagic("Dear compiler, T is whatever inherits from Foo.")]
abstract class Foo : Bar<T>
```

... such that an implementation of `Fizz` could simply be

```
class Fizz : Foo
```

Comment: No, this is not possible by default, but as it looks like you're shipping a library you could include some Roslyn build steps to do this for you.

Comment: That would be a viable option. I have not used Roslyn before - Do you have any pointers on how to get started with Roslyn on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's known as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Unfortunately, most strongly-typed languages have no way of removing this code smell. C# has no way to improve upon this.

You could resort to runtime checks, but at the expense of compile-time checking. Also, you wouldn't actually get to use the type in your class interface. For example, you wouldn't be able to do something like `abstract class Foo<T> { public T Bar() { ... } }` because `T` wouldn't be known by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what your looking for, but have you considered implementing an interface onto `Foo<T>` so you can always be sure what type the generic `T` will be?

```
public class Bar<T>
{}

public interface IDev
{}

public abstract class Foo<T> : Bar<T> where T : IDev
{}

public class Fizz : Foo<Fizz>, IDev
{}
```

It would give you some control over the generic object being passed in.

Comment: Yes, this is also what I do in the real implementation, which works for dictating that Fizz must be an IDev. Sadly, this does not get rid of the `Fizz : Foo<Fizz>` repetition.

Comment: I kinda guessed you would of had something in place after I submitted.  Sorry I cant be of any more help.

Answer (score 2):

> We also want to dictate that whatever class inherits from Foo is the specified type for T.

This requirement may be implemented as a custom Roslyn analyzer.

While this piece `abstract class Foo : Bar<T>` is unfortunately impossible, cause `T` generic parameter should be closed by some type or `Foo` must be generic as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Foo<T> : Bar<T>
    where T : Foo<T>
{ /* ... */ }

class Fizz : Foo<Fizz>
{ /* ... */ }
```

I know it's not what you're looking for, but it's best choice.